# How to run Fama-French four-factor model cross-country panel analysis?

Tags: asset-pricing, fama-french, paneldata

I am studying asset-pricing of "aircarft & defence" firms' stocks internationally covering **30 countries** over **1980-2016**. I can derive SMB, HML, and WML factors from Kenneth French's websites for **GLOBAL MARKETS**. 
How to conduct this four-factor analysis? Should I do panel analysis and account country-fixed effects, or just time-series analysis with global factors.
Please advice.

Comment: What's the research question? What question are you trying to answer?

Comment: it is a empirical research of 350 defense firms from 30 countries. I have monthly returns of them for period 1980-2016. I want to run Fama-French four factor regression to check if these stocks generate significant abnormal returns. I can retrieve RF (risk free rate), RM (benchmark market return), SMB, HML, and WML for global markets from Kenneth's website and run time-series regression. My confusing point is the data is panel data, it has stocks from several countries. So, should not I fix the country effect? If yes, how to do it in Fama-French 4 factor analysis?

Answer (score 2):

I think a useful paper would be Rapach et al. (2013), International Stock Return Predictability what is the role of the united states? They detail cross country differences in a lot of detail and tell you what you need to consider. In terms of time differences etc. It is also an easy to paper to digest and there is a summary on CFA digest.

Answer (score 1):

What you try to do is not clear.

1. If you want to reimplement FF factors on a custom universe, you can do it (but paying attention to timezones to not include future information in your data). But be careful: your result will only show you if there is a *cross-sectional Factorial effect* inside your firms.
2. May be you want in reality see if your firms have a specific loading according to FF factors of their countries. I.e. do your aircarft & defence firms have a bias in terms of Size, Value or Momentum? In such a case just take their loadings and average them.